# Publish HTML Test Report through email in Jenkins?

Tags: ant, selenium, junit, jenkins, report

I am using Jenkins and Ant. I am running Selenium and JUnit tests in Jenkins. I am able to generate HTML reports and emails to developers. I would like to publish the Jenkins unit test graph and HTML results in the email. So the graph should be included in the actual email, not just as a link.

I have tried Jelly HTML script in publishing the test results in the email. It is quite basic and does not really provide enough information.

Any ideas on how to nicely report unit test graph and pass/failures in email?

Comment: Is the graph part of the html file? You can include the HTML file as such in the extendable email content.

Comment: How do I include the HTML file? No, the graph is shown in Jenkins when looking at test results. I'm not sure what actually publishes it.

Comment: You can use this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin. Any file in your workspace can be added to the email using FILE token.

Comment: Interesting, is it possible to (either with token or JELLY) get a hook to the Unit test graph image, provided by Jenkins, and get the image displayed in the email up front?

Comment: As along as its a file, you can do it using the token. You need to insert the image file first and then the report.

Comment: The image is displayed on the Jenkins page like this:

Comment: <img lazymap="trendMap?rel=../&amp;width=800&amp;height=600" alt="[Test result trend chart]" src="trend?width=800&amp;height=600" usemap="#map0">

Comment: But I don't know how to access that image in email-ext

Comment: Right click on the image and find where its located using inspect element?? That will give you the physical path

Comment: Thanks, one more thing. Can I accesss the image file even if it's not located in the actual job workspace? I believe the unit test graph is located somewhere in the Jenkins file path, although I'm not sure.

Comment: Email-ext plugin allows you only to include the ones within workspace. If the file is outside workspace, you can write a simple shell or batch script to copy it to workspace. This script can be run as the last step of your build.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum up some key points from Jenkins report in plain text (like passed : 25, failed : 3, etc). Could be a workaround until you'll  find a true solution..